# Validating via AJAX a file input in a Laravel form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation, laravel

i'm trying to validate an image field in a Laravel form using AJAX but it allways seems to be empty. Even if i've already selected an file. How can i do it to check if the file input is empty or not with the ajax validation?

The form code:

```
{{ Form::open('files'=>'true') }}
    ...
    {{ Form::file('image') }}
    ...
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The AJAX call:

```
var form_data = $("#form").serialize();
$.ajax({
            dataType:"json",
            method:'post',
            url:'/ajax/validate?'+form_data,
            success:function(data){...}
});
```

The controller side:

```
...
$rules['image'] = 'required';
...
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);
if($validator->fails()){
    ...
}else{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

Mine was kinda fixed by replacing `serialize()` with `FormData()` . here is how it goes in **jquery/ajax**:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            url : '{{ URL::to('/post')}}',
            dataType : "json",
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success : function(response){
                if(response.success == true){
                    alert('done');
                }else{
                     $.each(response.errors,function(k,error){
                         alert(error);
                     }
                }
            }
        });
});
```

and in laravel validation you need to return response as jSon (I don't write complete code here):

```
if($validator->fails()){
    $errors = $validation->getMessageBag()->toArray();
    //Below Error also might work :
    //$errors = $validator->messages()->all();
    $result = ['success' => false , 'errors' => $errors];
}else{
     $result = ['success' => true, 'errors' => null];
}
return Response::json($result);
```

**Note**
I'm still working on this . I'm pretty sure it detects images because when (in my case) image size is more than 2MB it does not upload it.
it detects images if you use `FormData()` ...

I'm just not sure about the response.

Good Luck;

**EDIT**

To validate max file size, you should edit upload_max_filesize in your php.ini directly . otherwise Laravel might not be able to detect more than 2MB file size (I guess) because php itself stops it.

now my validation worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks to Alexandre Thebaldi , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279631/laravel-validation-max-rule-not-working-on-uploaded-image