# Laravel - Validation max rule not working on uploaded image

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm handling a file field with ajax request (FormData) to send an image to server.

Here is my php ajax handler

```
public function onUploadAvatar()
{
$photo = Request::file('avatar');

$avatar = new Controllers\AvatarController( $photo );

$validator = $avatar->validator();

if ( $validator->fails() )
{
  return [
    'success' => false,
    'validationErrors' => $validator->errors()
  ];
}

$moved = $avatar->attach();

if ( $moved !== false )
{
  return [
    'success' => true,
    'avatarPath' => $moved
  ];
}
}
```

Below my validator method

```
  public function validator()
  {
    $input = [
      'avatar' => $this->photo
    ];

    $rules = [
      'avatar' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:1048576'
    ];

    $messages = [
      'mimes' => 'invalid format',
      'max' => 'please 1MB',
      'image' => 'please image'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make( $input, $rules, $messages );

    return $validator;
  }
```

When i send some file with size less than `max` rule, i have the expected response:

[image]
[image]

**THE PROBLEM**

But when i upload file with more than `max`, i have this (response) error:

[image]
[image]

The anothers validation rules is working.

**ADITIONAL INFORMATION**

Returning some data after request:

```
return [
  'photo' => Request::file('avatar'),
  'hasFile' => Request::hasFile('avatar'),
  'extension' => Request::file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension(),
  'size' => Request::file('avatar')->getClientSize()
];
```

**RESPONSES:**

File less than `max`:

```
{"photo":{},"hasFile":true,"extension":"jpg","size":900498}
```

File with more than `max`:

```
{"photo":{},"hasFile":false,"extension":"jpg","size":0}
```

**SOLUTION**

I expected some feedback as *The file "file.jpg" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive* for php.ini fails related to the max size. Only increased **upload_max_filesize** directive and worked. No more problem.